# Sound Gone from 18.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 18.10

Upgraded yesterday to the latest version of Ubuntu via commandline. No problem during the install, it restarted and I had sound and everything is fine. However, since this morning, all my sound has gone! I checked settings, nothing muted, I reloaded ALSA, checked PulseAudio, rebooted a couple of times, but nothing is happening.

I know Ubuntu seems to have issues with with my sound card, Creative Audio SoundBlaster Core 3D SB1570 SB AudigyFx, but does anyone have a solution, like a generic driver that it will work with?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug at launchpad for it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1799007

As I said there, seems to have an way to get pulseaudio working, but it still doesn't with the system:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio
$ pulseaudio
```

At restart, you still need to run the `pulseaudio` comand again.